# Cannot cast object '(10)' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.lang.Integer'

Tags: oracle, plsql, jasper-reports

I am using `ireport 3.7.1`. I have made a connection with my database.I have a procedure which when given an input in number ,it returns the word format of the number i.e if I give input 10,it will return ten. The problem is when I am executing the procedure in `pl/sql` developer,I am getting the proper output but when I am firing the same procedure in `ireport` it's giving me this exception
`Cannot cast object '(10)' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.lang.Integer'` .

Comment: PL/SQL can transparently cast from string to numbers. Java requires a call to `parseInt` to do that.  In both cases `(10)` isn't a valid number. Maybe you should provide the relevant _few_ lines of your code -- both working and not working. _And_ dump the content of your value each time.

Answer (score 2):

Casting straight from a String to an Integer is not possible. You'll want to use the function `Integer.parseInt(stringNumber);`

Answer (score 0):

`(10)` isn't a properly formated integer. Not even for PL/SQL:

```
select '(10)' +0 from dual;

> ORA-01722: invalid number
```

I could only suggest you to trace back the point where those `(` `)` come from. And fix your code at *that* position instead. Just a wild guess, some number formats use parenthesis to represent *negative* numbers. Maybe this is your case?

---

That being said, if you still want to locally remove the parenthesis that have somehow lurked inside of your string:

```
String str = "(10)";
int value = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(1, str.length()-1));
//                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                   *blindly* get away of first and last character
//                    assuming those are `(` and `)`
```

For something a little bit more robust, and assuming parenthesis denotes negative numbers, you should try some regex:

```
    String str = "(10)";
    str = str.replaceFirst("\\(([0-9]+)\\)", "-$1");
    //                      ^^^        ^^^    ^
    //                   replace integer between parenthesis by its negative value
    //                   i.e.: "(10)" become "-10" (as a *string*)

    int value = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot friends for the replies